how to train equivariant transformer on atomic coordinate data
i'm new to using transformers. i'm trying to use the equiformer model docs here to train a score function on atomic coordinate data. the atomic coordinate data is an Nx3 array, where N is the number of atoms and 3 because of 3 spatial dimensions. likewise, i also have an Nx118 array of one-hot encoded labels for each atom type (118 because of 118 atoms in periodic table).
however, i am confused on how to train this model. i would normally provide some code for this but ive tried so many things that it seems pretty frivolous to include anything.
its a very simple short script that im looking for, and would like to ask anyone of you who might be experienced with this type of model.
just assume the loss function is an empty return statement.
thanks
i tried inputting my Nx118 atom labels into the "feats" parameter but it gave me a ton of random errors, notably that my dim must be equal to 2.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's best to refer to the author of the repository and ask them. This is a project specific issue and the authors of the repository are the best one to answer you.

if your feat is the one hot encode with dim of (x size that not 1) with node (N) you may add the another dimension for graph the final shape will be torch.size(1, N_node, M_feat). as you may see in the example of "adjacency matrix" Do you work on drug - ligand interaction?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
